# 3D plots wrongly displayed when using GraphicsRow in Linux

Tags: front-end, linux

I get an incorrect vertical offset in 3D plots when using GraphicsRow in Mathematica 9 (Linux - Ubuntu 12.04). When displayed by itself, the plot is fine. Here's an example:

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
```

Showing the plot by itself works as expected:

```
a = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Gaussian shown once]

However  an incorrect vertical offset appears when showing the plot *multiple* times with GraphicsRow:

```
GraphicsRow[{a, a}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Gaussian shown twice]

Does anybody also have this problem? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Doesn't it work `GraphicsRow[{a, a}, ImageSize -> Large]` either ?

Comment: Nasser: Your plots look OK... On my side the surfaces (not the axes) are offset by about -.5 (sorry if I can't post an image - I'm new and do not have enough points yet).

Comment: Artes: the problem is the same when I use GraphicsRow[{a, a}, ImageSize -> Large]. As Nasser suggests, this might be an issue with the Linux version.

Comment: Jerome, you should post your update as an answer instead, since it solves the problem. I know that as a new user you might not be able to post a self-answer until after about 8 hrs of asking, but please consider posting it after the time has passed :)

Comment: No issue on Fedora 17 64 bit with 3D acceleration (nVidia).

Comment: @Jerome Can you please post a screenshot of the problem in the question (to make it very clear what this is about) and post your finding as an answer?  This might help other Linux users who run into this problem.  Please also try starting Mathematica with the option `mathematica -mesa` and see if that fixed the problem.

Comment: A little late to be sure, but in the hope that someone may benefit, I don't see this using Ubuntu 12.04 with nvidia 304 drivers.  That's native -- no VMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of this: it was not a problem with Mathematica but with 3D acceleration within a virtual machine (my Linux setup: Ubuntu 12.04 running in VMware 8 on a Windows 7 host). After disabling hardware acceleration for the VM the plots with GraphicsRow now look OK.

```
 GraphicsRow[{a, a}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Gaussian shown twice, without the offset]

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  It would be helpful to future visitors if you would also attach an image of the problem to the question.